# How promise chains reference the next error handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am wondering if anyone knows how promise chains reference the next error handler - for example:

```
  const p = new Promise(resolve => resolve(5))
   .then(v => 5*v)
   .then(v => { throw 'foo' });

  p.then(v => v/4)
   .then(v => v+3)
   .catch(e => console.error('first catch:', e));

  p.then(v => v/4)
   .then(v => v+3)
   .catch(e => console.error('second catch:', e));
```

If you run that you will get:

```
first catch: foo
second catch: foo
```

to my knowledge, every time `Promise.prototype.then` is a called, a new promise is created and returned. The only way I can think of for the promise to be able to find the *next error handler* for each chain, is to have an array of references to the children. So if a Promise is rejected, it would go through all the children and find the closest rejection handlers in each child chain.

Does anyone know how this is implemented?

Comment: const p is a rejected promise - do you know that? re-reading question, I think you probably do - sorry

Comment: What you're asking about is an implementation detail, and that would depend on which browser (for native promises) or which library (for 3rd party promises). In general, though, promises would need to keep track of their immediate children so that they can notify them when they've resolved or rejected. They would not need to keep track of a handler several degrees of separation away because each `.then` or `.catch` creates a new promise with its own "children".

Answer (score 8):

The way I see it:

Think of promises as nested arrays:

`[then1,[then1.1, then1.2, catch1.1, then1.3, then1.4], then2, catch1]`

looks like this:

```
new Promise(...)
.then(() => {         // <- 1
  return Promise(...)
          .then()     // <- 1.1
          .then()     // <- 1.2
          .catch()    // <- 1.1
          .then()     // <- 1.3
          .then()     // <- 1.4
})
.then()               // <- 2
.catch()              // <- 1
```

Now imagine we start execution and it begins in the topmost array. We have an index for each array specifying which element we are waiting for in terms of execution.
We start off by calling `.then1`, which itself returns a promise chain (another array). When an error occurs your lowest in hierarchy array (the deepest one) **skips through (doesn't execute)** it's elements until it finds a `catch`. If it does, it executes the `catch` and continues executing the other elements. If it doesn't find a `catch` it asks the parent array to find and execute a `catch`, skipping all elements **including its children arrays because they are not catch**.

In our example if an error occurs in `then1.2` it will be caught by `catch1.1`, but if it occurs in `then1.3` it will propagate all the way to `catch1` skipping `then1.4` and `then2`

Edit:

Here is code to experiment with:

```
new Promise(res => res())
.then(() => 
    new Promise(res => res())
    .then(() => console.log(1))
    .then(() => {console.log(2); throw "Error 1"})
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    .then(() => {console.log(3); throw "Error 2"}))
    .then(() => console.log(4))
.then(() => 
    new Promise(res => res())
    .then(() => console.log(6))
    .then(() => {console.log(7); throw "Error 3"})
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    .then(() => console.log(8))
    .then(() => {console.log(9); throw "Error 4"}))
.then(() => console.log(10))
.catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

it logs:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> Error 1
>
> 3
>
> Error 2

Comment: yep it's like a tree, with each promise referencing its children.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Promises aren't nested arrays, they are nested entities/contexts. I'm going to be leaving out the reference to the resolution context here, but they are closer to the following example `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(2))` is actually a `Promise(Promise(2))`. Promise.resolve(2).catch(console.log)` is actually a `Catch(Promise(2))`. `Promise.resolve(2).then(() => Promise.reject(new Error('2')).catch(console.log)` is `Catch(Then(Promise))`

Comment: Shorter buzzwords: It's composition, not nesting

Comment: @RobertMennell I never said they were implemented by nested arrays, just made an analogy that helps colleagues understand it more easily :)

Comment: Except after stepping through this example I see the same mistake the asker is wanting clarification on. The first catch isn't on `1.1` as you stated. It's actually on `1.2`. If I branch a new promise off of `1.1` and throw, that catch won't receive the error on that chain.

Comment: @RobertMennell My bad, `catch 1.2` was not supposed to be in the example at all. Other than that, branching off and throwing still supports my claim

Comment: The `new Promise(res => res())` parts are redundant. Just indent the chain and match up `(` `)`s.

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov I'm not sure what you mean by supports your claim

Answer (score 2):

So let's just step through your example first.

```
const p = new Promise(resolve => resolve(5))
 .then(v => 5*v)
 .then(v => { throw 'foo' });

p.then(v => v/4)
 .then(v => v+3)
 .catch(e => console.error('first catch:', e));

p.then(v => v/4)
 .then(v => v+3)
 .catch(e => console.error('second catch:', e));
```

Here you actually have 3 different promises:

`p` which is `Promise.then.then`, `anonymous` which is `p.then.then.catch`, and `anonymous` which is `p.then.then.catch`.

Remember that `Promise.then` and `Promise.catch` return Promises that encompass the Promise from before. So what you're really ending up with is nested promises with those three promise chains.

When `p` eventually throws in the third promise at evaluation the other two promises are now checking the return type, flags, and other internal information that eventually leads to them realizing a promise from earlier in the chain rejected and thus it must reject too. You can also emulate this with the following:

```
var p = Promise.reject(new Error('Hi from p!'))

p.catch(e => console.log('Hello from a different promise', p))
==
p.catch(e => console.log('Hello from a yet different promise', p))
```

You should notice that the return of the evaluation is false which means the two objects aren't equal.

Now what happens if we wait a bit and then attach a new catch handler to `p`?

```
setTimeout(() => p.catch(console.log), 500)
```

You should notice another console log, this time with only 'Hi from p!'

And the reason is order at which a Promise evaluates. It evaluates on creation and if it's created on a rejected promise, it evaluates to rejected and goes to the catch handler.

What do you think you'll get with the following?

```
Promise
  .reject(new Error('1'))
  .catch(console.log)
  .then(() => Promise.reject(new Error('2')))
  .then(() => new Error('3'))
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log)
  .catch(() => console.log('4'))
```

That's right you'll see a printed Error('1'), then a printed Error('2'), but not a printed Error('3') or a printed '4'. That's because a `.catch` promise does one of two things: resolves the promise to the resolved value, or resolves the promise to the functions value if the chain is rejected.

In contrast `.then` only resolves a promise. If it's resolution is  rejected, it rejects with the resolution.

It's a little confusing yes, but once you realize that promise will wait for resolution and will check and chaining promises it becomes a little easier to figure out where you'll reject to.